# What is the maximum number of members a class can have in c++

Tags: c++, class, member

Please take this query as a question of curiosity.

I just want to know that is there any limitation in the number of members a class can have in c++. Hope there will be some maximum allowed number since everything will be finite in a language I guess.

Comment: Almost certain to be implementation defined, and the usual warning of "if you have to ask, you're doing something wrong"

Comment: There is no limit defined in the specification - it would all depend on the platform and it's compiler. There is a minimum that each compiler should support, however. Its 16384.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Think this is not the right way to comment for a genuine question. Of course I accept your comment. But prefer answers than comments.

Comment: It's a comment because it doesn't answer your question as posed. But I was trying to point out that your question as posed isn't likely to have an answer.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Saying "it's implementation defined" *is* an answer. Just because it isn't a number doesn't mean that it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: you can find a detailed answer [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619340/maximum-number-of-fields-for-a-c-object

Comment: This question is ambiguous^Wclear, vague^Wprecise, incomplete^Wcomplete, overly broad^W^Wnarrow, or^Wand rhetorical^Wintended to be answered and cannot^Wcan be reasonably answered in its current form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That value is defined by each implementation. The C++ standard recommends some minimum supported quantities in Annex B:

> — Data members in a single class [16 384].
>
> [...]
>
> — Direct and indirect base classes [16 384].
>
> — Direct base classes for a single class [1 024].
>
> — Members declared in a single class [4 096].
>
> — Final overriding virtual functions in a class, accessible or not [16
>   384].
>
> — Direct and indirect virtual bases of a class [1 024].
>
> — Static members of a class [1 024].

The minimum for "members declared in a single class" is less than the one for "data members in a single class" because classes can inherit data members from their bases.

Comment: And that ought to be enough for everyone. Seriously :)

Comment: Why is data members in a single class 4 times more than members declared in a single class? If the difference is that "members" include "data members" and "member functions" then the there should be allowed more "members" than "data members". What am I missing? O_O

Comment: @Armen: I already edited that explanation in! Refresh your browser!

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Ah, I see