# Spring JDBC query to pull 30000 rows is hanging

Tags: java, performance

I have a table having 30000 rows and when I am trying to pull one single column into a List of type String, the query is hanging for ever. If I apply check to pull only few rows it is working fine.

**Below is my Method to pull the data.**

public class HeFeaturesJdbcRepository {

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public List<String> getAllProductIdCodes() {
    return jdbcTemplate.query("select distinct product_id_code from saa_dim_product",
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper(String.class));
}
```

}

**It works fine if I put a logic to pull few rows.**

public List getAllProductIdCodes() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("select distinct product_id_code from saa_dim_product **where rownum<=10**",
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper(String.class));
    }

Also I increased my JVM memory to 3gb to check.
Much appreciate your inputs.

Thanks`enter code here`

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to retrieve 30000 rows at once? I will recommend retrieve and process it in batches

Comment: I want to have this requirement as this is a reference data and want to store it inside a collection and use that for checking.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the way you use it for checking? Also, does hanging meant running for a long time or the application is not responding?

Comment: When I am executing from the Eclipse tool it is just hanging there and not doing anything. I am using this data to populate in a List and use it to check for the data.

Comment: Does it throw any error at the end?

Comment: I did not wait unitl then. Wondering whether Spring application can pull say 100000 rows and store in 1 variable or not possible at all.

Comment: It depends on the size of your data. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36155687/6624509) might help a little

Comment: And for your application that seems to run forever, you can try to print something in the console for every 100 or 500 rows you process to see if it is running. I suspect that it's running, but very slowly